# SSH Port forwarding on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, port-forwarding, putty

How can I enable port forwarding for SSH in Windows 10? This is from my Ubuntu box.

```
Host ahost
 Hostname ipaddress1
 User usernamehere

Host ahost2
 HostName ipaddress2
 User usernamehere
 LocalForward 5440 externalip:port
 LocalForward 5400 externalip:port
 LocalForward 3300 externalip:port
 ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p ahost
```

Is there a way with putty? since it is SSH tunneling I think.

Comment: please better describe your network. you port forward on a gateway router device. Is your win10 system configured as a gateway router? what roles do the win10 and ubuntu boxes play in the network, where are they in relation to eachother, and where will the remote clients be?

Comment: It is just a way for me to ssh into an EC2 computer and tunnel some local ports to that EC2 computer. If that makes sense.

Comment: ahh, ok you are tunneling, not port forwarding. gotcha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, putty can do port forwarding. Its in the Connection -> Ssh -> Tunnel section of the config.

[image: putty-screenshot].

Just enter the local port in `Source port` and the externalip:port as the `Destination`.

For the proxy command see this link.

https://monkeyswithbuttons.wordpress.com/2010/10/01/ssh-proxycommand-and-putty/

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent in PuTTY is "local proxy command". You can use the [`plink.exe`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) with the [`-nc` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-ncmode) instead of the `ssh` with the `-W` switch.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this worked on Windows 10:

```
ssh -N -f user@host -L port:localhost:port
```

Comment: So first, yes, good to point out that Windows has (for some years) supported ssh, reducing the need for PuTTY. As for that -f arg, though, for me it causes an error, "Cannot fork into background without a command to execute." If I remove it, then the ssh and port forwarding works...but it ALSO opens a remote shell/command line. For those who would not want that, add the -N arg (and instead of -f, if you get this error I do).

Comment: You can throw a `tail -f /dev/null` at the end to give it a command to be able to fork it.